# Как создать generics через передаваемый аргумент Class?

Tags: java, generics

Можно ли каким нибудь способом создать дженерик из передаваемого объекта типа Class?

```
public void createGeneric(Class<?> clazz) {
        
        List<clazz.getName> someList = ...?
        
        ...
}
```

P.S.: Если передавать в параметр **Т,** то получится `List<Class<T>>`, а мне нужен `List<T>`

Comment: Мне кажется вы не понимаете как это работает. И не понимаете, что хотите в итоге. Вариант, который я вам предложил наиболее подходящий.

Comment: Возможно, можете посоветовать что-нибудь почитать?

Comment: Найдите главу про обобщения в книге `Философия Java` (можно найти pdf в инете). Как по мне, то там автор нормально объясняет эту тему. Или [тут](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.11.php) еще почитайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public <T> void createGeneric(T clazz) {
    List<T> someList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```